# Bluetooth not working at first boot

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04, bluetooth, iwlwifi

My laptop is AMD 5900HX with Intel AX200 wifi+bluetooth module. I am running on Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 6.2.14.

When I have to shutdown and boot my laptop again bluetooth does not work. It works if I reboot.

Sometimes it works without a reboot if I do `modprobe -r btusb && modprobe -r btintel` followed by `modprobe btintel && modprobe btusb`. Not always.
Journalctl shows the following error with bluetooth after booting -

```
May 06 14:22:18 compu kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
May 06 14:22:18 compu kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version command failed (-110)
```

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: The 6.2 kernel is not yet available for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS; are you using Ubuntu? if so have you tried the *supported* kernel stacks (GA, HWE etc)

Comment: Yes. I did with kernel 5.19.0.41 and I still had the problem. There is an additional thing. I am in South Africa and we have ocassional blackouts. Bluetooth is not working at first boot if I restart my laptop after power supply is restored. When I shutdown and restart while power supply is active then Bluetooth works even at first boot, even if the restart is after a few hours .